# Can Resharper create a method directly in an existing region?

Tags: c#, resharper, region

A lot of the time I find classes end up with a few small 'helper' methods, which are usually commonly used in the class but whose implementation is unlikely to change often.

I tend to put these in a region near the bottom of the class, helpfully entitled *helper methods*. When I want a new one I just type out the method name where I need to use it and let Resharper's `Create method` function extract the definition.

By default, this is added below the current method, wherever that is, with `throw new NotImplementedException();` as the body. Is there any way of telling Resharper to put this new method directly into my helper region? I've had a look around and have not found anything.

I'd expect a `Create method in region...` which could provide a pick list of the regions in the class* would help to organise things a little faster. That's what the regions are for, after all.

* Yes, I realise you can define regions anywhere you like, so many would not be valid places for methods to go. That's an implementation detail, I would say.

Comment: I guess you already do it by this way: Move generated method into region via Drag&Drop in *File Structure* window.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, +1 to brgerner. This is the most obvious way to do this, and arguably the only way (except for [writing your own ReSharper plug-in](http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/getting-started-with-resharper-sdk)) if these helper methods don't follow a certain naming convention.

However, if they follow a naming convention, you can [modify the default type member layout](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/01/in-depth-look-at-customizing-type-layout-with-resharper/), which will allow you to rearrange these methods in a region with every code cleanup run.

Say, if your helper method names always have the `Helper` prefix, you can put the following entry as the last entry within the `Pattern` tag:

```
        <!--Helper methods-->
        <Entry>
            <Match>
                <And>
                    <Kind Is="method"/>
                    <Name Is="Helper.*" IgnoreCase="true" />
                </And>
            </Match>
            <Group>
                <Name Region="Helper methods"/>
            </Group>
        </Entry>
```

Now, you can rearrange your helper methods every time you're running [Full Cleanup](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Cleanup__Running_Code_Cleanup.html), or you can even [create a separate code cleanup profile](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Cleanup__Creating_Custom_Profiles.html) that would only apply your custom type members layout rule, and wouldn't touch anything else.